# Splitting a string into fixed-length lines of text with word-breaking

Tags: c#, split

I need to take an input string and break it into lines following these rules:

1. lines must be less than or equal to 80 characters.
2. lines must split on the space, not breaking words in two.

I've tried this three times, but my code is just terrible.

```
foreach (ChoiceClass c in q.ChoiceTextArray)
{
    int runningIndex = 0;
    int m = Math.Max(c.Description.Length - 1, 80);
    int numLines = (c.Description.Length / 80) + 1;

    while (numLines > 0)
    {
        int len = 80;
        if (numLines == 1)
        {
            len = c.Description.Length - runningIndex;
        }

        string tmp = string.Empty;
        if (numLines > 1)
        {
            tmp = c.Description.Substring(runningIndex, len);
        }
        else
        {
            if (runningIndex > c.Description.Length)
            {
                richTextBox2.Text += "\t" + tmp + eol;
                runningIndex += tmp.Length + 1;
                numLines--;
            }
            else
            {
                tmp = c.Description.Substring(runningIndex);
                richTextBox2.Text += "\t" + tmp + eol;
                runningIndex += tmp.Length + 1;
                numLines--;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "My code is just terrible" isn't a question. Does it work? Good. Do you want it to be shorter or more readable? Try to ask on Code Review, but not before reading their http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestion. I will do that from now on. -Su

Comment: That's a late reply! Happy to have been useful two years ago. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working example now!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string somethingLongToPrint = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

       int i = 0;
       string tmp = string.Empty;
       string overrun = string.Empty;
       int len = somethingLongToPrint.Length - 1; // 0-based counting
       while( i < len)
       {
           if (overrun != string.Empty)
           {
               // to keep the length down to 80 and still account for overrun, i should subtract the length of overrun
               // If the number of characters left in "somethingLongToPrint" is less than 80, then then
               int numberOfCharactersRemaining = somethingLongToPrint.Length - i;
               if (numberOfCharactersRemaining > 80)
               {
                   tmp = overrun + somethingLongToPrint.Substring(i - overrun.Length, 80);
               }
               else
               {
                   tmp = overrun + somethingLongToPrint.Substring(somethingLongToPrint.Length - numberOfCharactersRemaining);
               }
           }
           else
           {
               tmp = somethingLongToPrint.Substring(i, ((80 - overrun.Length)));
           }
           overrun = print80CharacterLine(tmp);
           i += 80;
       }

    }

    // returns what was not printed
    private string print80CharacterLine(string src)
    {
        string eol = "\r\n";

        string whatIsLeft = string.Empty;

        int index = src.LastIndexOf(" ");

        string calculatedString = src.Substring(0, index);

        whatIsLeft = src.Substring((index+1));

        // print statement here
        // do the e.Graphics.DrawString(lines[linesPrinted], someFont, brush, x, y);
        textBox1.Text += calculatedString + eol;

        return whatIsLeft;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the code is much better than yours... no else statements

```
var text =
            @"this a asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf wdbwbwrthwrthw rthwrth wth wrt h wrn wrnbfb  wbwbwbb s  jkvjv j j o o  , , mfnfnsxuiua sdf asdfas dfasd f
asdf asd fasdf asdf asdf asdf asd fasdf asd fasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asd fasdf as
df asd fasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf ";

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var currentLine = String.Empty;
        var split = text.Split(' ');

        foreach (var s in split)
        {
            if (s.Length >= 80)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLine))
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(currentLine);
                    currentLine = "";
                }

                sb.AppendLine(s);
                continue;
            }

            if ((String.Format("{0} {1}", currentLine, s).Length > 80))
            {
                sb.AppendLine(currentLine);
                currentLine = "";
            }

            currentLine += s + " ";
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLine))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(currentLine);
        }

        var final = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: This looks very promising. I will try it ASAP

Comment: I tried it, but the output places a single two-letter word on a line. It was close! I think the answer is
(1) Write a method that takes a string 80-characters long as input.
(2) print each character one at a time until you reach the final space, then stop.
(3) Use content.LastIndexOf(" "); to get the last index of the final space.

Comment: Is the single two-letter word because you used a string that has a remainder of 2 when you divide the length by 80?  When I run your `somethingLongToPrint` string, the output is correct.  What string did you test against?

Comment: I created a sample WinForms app, with a button to execute the method and a textbox that shows each line processed.

Comment: I don't care how you tested it, I'm interested in what string you tested with to get your 2 characters on one line?

Comment: I'm sorry, Jacob, I used the sample string provided by your code.

Answer (score 0):

Split paragraph to fixed length lines without breaking the words

```cs
    static IEnumerable<string> FunctionSplit(string stringToSplit, int maximumLineLength)
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        string[] words = stringToSplit.Trim().Split(' ');
        string line = string.Empty;
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            line = $"{line} {word}".Trim();
            if (line.Length >= maximumLineLength)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
                line = string.Empty;                       
            }
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            lines.Add(line);
        }            
        return lines;
    }
```

Comment: Split paragraph to fixed length lines without breaking the words